# Egg Hatching In Pokemon-Go

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it normal to hatch an egg on pokemon go, and no pokemon come out of it? I tried reloading the app and still nothing came up, but I had more stardust than before.

Comment: Did you check your pokemon bag then sort by recent? See if you have something new.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me (and to others) as well.  I suspect it's one of the many glitches with the game.  And it occurs when the egg hatches while you're busy doing something else in the game, such as battling in a gym or evolving something while walking.